# How can I solve this issue in django without changing the models?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-generic-views

## Info

- I have two simple models in Django, with one-to-one relationship
- I'm using generic views
- There are `Issue`s and `Solutions`s in the database, numbered 1 through 10
- Loading the `Issue` via the `DetailView` (e.g. `localhost:8000/myapp/6/`) works great

## Error

When trying to load the `Solution` view in a browser (e.g. `localhost:8000/myapp/6/solution/`), I get `Page not found (404), No solution found matching the query`.

## Code

*models.py*:

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.issue_text
    issue_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Solution(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.solution_text
    issue = models.OneToOneField(Issue, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    solution_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

*views.py*:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Issue
    template_name = 'my_templates/detail.html'

class SolutionView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Solution
    template_name = 'my_templates/solution.html'
```

*urls.py*:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/solution/$', views.SolutionView.as_view(), name='solution'),
]
```

## Question

I suspect that maybe the relationship between the models is incorrect - I can see that the view raises the 404 error because it can't find a `solution` object (though there are a few `solution` objects in the database, for every `Issue`).

I've been going through [Django's docs on generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) and [making Django queries to the database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/) but I think I'm confusing the two.

Also, debugging with `pdb` just makes the browser lose the object for some reason.

Did I get the one-to-one relationship wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mismatch between the app name and the object instance.

In this case, the app, the module and the model objects were named differently. For example - following [django's tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/): the name of the app should be `polls` and the templates sub-directory should also be `polls/templates/polls`, but in this case the app was named something like `polls_app` and the templates sub-directory something like `polls_templates`. Any other naming mismatch results in the same way.

I found this while trying to run tests in django - even though everything else worked (other than this specific, generic view), the tests failed with an error. Investigating that error led me to the tests `runner` code (see [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/71756bdfed5029bd14dce8cb3c5629efc4be55ac/django/test/runner.py) or [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/test/runner/)) and `loadTestsFromName` in it.

So I guess that django relies on the object name (in the example above - it was searching for `polls` in `polls_templates` or something similar), but I couldn't find how this can be configured. Trying to debug it with `pdb` wans't great either, since I was getting way deep into django's source code.

I created a new app, with everything named the same, and now tests are running ok, and also the `SolutionView`, so having everything called by the same name solved the question for me.

I assume that there's a similar name-relying module in django's `url` which does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Which Django Version did you use? try this...

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('solution/<int:pk>/', SolutionView.as_view(), name='solution'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class SolutionView(DetailView):
    model = Solution
    template_name ="my_templates/solution.html"


    def get_object(self):
        some_pk = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        return get_object_or_404(Solution, pk=some_pk)
```

Tested. This works for me fine. It´s django 3.0 but i guess down to version 2.x this should also work.

you have to send the integer variable from your request to your class based view `some_pk` so that django can get the right object.

`page not found` relates also to your template path - so check it.

Don´t forget to set the right `template_name` and to import everything.

Comment: Thanks @black_hole_sun, I tried your idea, but no change... when I run the server and go to the solution URL (.../[SOME_PK]/solution/) I get django's 404 (page not found / Raised by: app.views.SolutionView / No Solution matches the given query). Can you please explain the logic behind this? I mean, why does overriding get_object with a different <pk> would help?

Comment: @somethingorange updated my answer above. if you have still issues. please provide more info. traceback etc.

Comment: I tried the updated answer: I'm still getting "Page not found (404)" error (Using the URLconf defined... Django tried these URL patterns, in this order... The current path, [PATH], didn't match any of these... You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True...). For PATH I tried several urls and played with the url arguments a little... all resulted in 404 :|

Comment: I think I'm getting the models relationship wrong... I mean, the view tries to find a "solution" object, but maybe the one-to-one relationship fails in database? is it possible that there's no "solution" object related to the <pk> it tries to query? (I'll update the question too)

Comment: Hey @black_hole_sun, I solved my question - I guess it had some naming issues, and django relies on that. Errors don't give much information in that case, as it turns out. Thanks so much for trying to help ;) it's very much appreciated